# Rails: Selecting from multiple tables using .join()

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Plugins Model:

```
class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :report
    has_many :vulns
end
```

Vulns Model:

```
class Vuln < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plugins
end
```

I'm doing the following in rails:

```
#using * for now to select everything    
@data = Plugin.select("*").joins(:vulns).where('plugins.id'=> plugin.plugin_id)
```

Which does the following query in the terminal:

```
SELECT * FROM `plugins` INNER JOIN `vulns` ON `vulns`.`plugin_id` = `plugins`.`id` WHERE `plugins`.`id` = 186
```

It's the right query but it doesn't select the content from the vulns table. I know it's the right query because I tried it in phpmyadmin and it returned the data on the vulns table too. When I do it in rails (using `<%= debug(@data) %>`) it only shows content from the plugins table.

How do I make it select everything from the vulns table too? (Each plugin has multiple vulns)

Comment: Is `vulns` populated in the returned plugins?

Comment: Yes, `vulns` is populated in the returned plugins when I do it through mysql or phpmyadmin, but vulns doesn't even show up when I do it through Rails

Comment: Just made sure: caching is off and I'm using Rails 4 in development mode

Comment: Figured it out. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't have a column with the name "type".

If anybody has similar issues, rename the column called "type". I generated a new migration:

```
rails g migration RenameColumnOnVulnsTable
```

And then added the following:

```
def change
  rename_column :vulns, :type, :vulnerability_type
end
```

The query works fine now.